# Vertical coverflow for android

Tags: android, coverflow

I want to create list of objects with coverflow effect for Android. Very similar to this lib - https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow , but for vertical mode. I found difficult to modify this library for vertical displaying. Are there any solutions for Android?

Comment: Start with changing all horizontal with vertical: https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=horizontal

Comment: @piotrek1543 already tried to change x to y axis, a lot of code changes : touches handling, drawing, measuring, etc

Comment: so create an issue on project's Github page and ask an author how to do it, Maybe another developer using this library may you help